# Twitter Bootstrap 3 accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to integrate twitter bootstrap3 accordion in my web project. I have got the accordion to show up in the page, but the collapse and expansion of the accordion does not seems to work correctly. I appreciate if someone can tell me what is that I am doing incorrect.

This is my code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" data-bind="foreach:{data:products,afterRender:expand}">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class=" panel-title colorgrey" data-parent="#accordion" data-bind="attr:{href:link}">
            <h4 >
                <span data-bind="text:product"></span>
                <span id="arrowicon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-large glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right orange paddingbottom"></span>
            </h4>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="attr:{id:target},foreach:recipes" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span data-bind="text:RecipeTitle"></span>
            <span id="arrowicon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-large glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right orange paddingbottom"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle for this one?

Comment: @ndcweb sure. will do that now

Comment: If by 'not working correctly' you mean it's not doing anything, perhaps you're forgetting the Bootstrap JS and/or jQuery?

Comment: @ParrotMac : I meant the toggle functionality of the accordion is not working. I have got the accordion coming up in the page. But its always in the expand mode, even if i click on the accordion header, it does not close

Comment: ndcweb : I cannot get this working on jsfiddle on bootply, I have a few data-bindings applied with the help of knockout as you can see.

Comment: Just copy and paste in the output into a jsfiddle or bootply.  That's what folks will need anyway to diagnose the issue and provide feedback.

Comment: I suspect your data-bindings aren't matching up for the href and the anchor tag.  Look at the output and make sure that the link output looks like this:  href="#id_of_the_target_with_panel-collapse_class" if it doesn't, then that would definitely produce the result you described (always expanded).  If you forgot the js or it wasn't reading the js file, the css would cause all of the panels to be hidden and not togglable.